# UnimplementedFeatureError: Nested dynamic arrays not implemented here

Tags: solidity, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

// delete an array of names
contract ArrayDelete {
string[] names;

function main() returns (string[]) {
   names.push("Jones");
   names.push("Ama");
   names.push("Emeka");
   names.push("Owo");
   names.push("Lulu");

   delete names[0];
   return names;
 }
}
```

Any ideas why this error occurs? None of the answers on similar questions was helpful in fixing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't return a dynamic array of dynamic arrays from a Solidity function. From the [Solidity docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/frequently-asked-questions.html#is-it-possible-to-return-an-array-of-strings-string-from-a-solidity-function):

> Is it possible to return an array of strings (string[]) from a Solidity function?
>
> Not yet, as this requires two levels of dynamic arrays (string is a dynamic array itself).

Comment: "You can't return a dynamic array from a Solidity function." This is inaccurate. You can return a dynamic array, but you can't return a dynamic array _of dynamic arrays_. (`string` is a dynamic array.) So a return type of `uint256[]` is fine but not `string[]`.

Comment: So anything method that has to deal with something similar will have make use of   numbers? What's the work around for doing this with strings ?

Comment: It's 2022 and this is no longer a problem, thanks to ABIEncoderV2 which is enabled by default since Solidity v0.8. You can safely return a dynamic array of dynamic arrays, such as `string[]`.